# TexWorks.0.4.5 completely changed the text in the editor

Tags: texworks

Sorry this is a little vague, I'm *totally* baffled by it.  I've been using TexWorks intensively for a few years.  I just upgraded it from 0.4.3 to 0.4.5.  Now the text in the editor appears in ALL CAPS, in a bizarre font.  When I compile my document, the output is correct (i.e. mixed case) - even though *ALL* the words appear in CAPS in the editor.  Which makes it utterly unuseable.  I'm so baffled I don't even know where to start.  Can anyone point me a little bit in the right direction?
On a related note, my frustration with TexWorks has been building enormously in recent months - is this still a reasonable tool to use, or has it been supersided by something much better these days?  Any and all pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a strong `emacs` gang lurking in the site and they will say "Use emacs" ;)

Comment: Is this one file or all files? If one, I would first check the file in a text editor such as `vim`. (Or `emacs` if you insist. ;) More seriously, any plain text editor - `nano`, `pico`, `gedit`, whatever Windows has... Check the file encoding etc. If it is all files, I would either switch editors (since you seem to fancy a change) or backup the config for TW and see if the problem occurs with a non-customised run. That will at least help to narrow the problem down.

Comment: And which font does the editor use and did you try to change it? (imho under format ->font or something like this)

Comment: For something different see the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Format->font fixed that, thanks, I didn't try that b/c I figured there's no ALL-CAPS font.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks, that's exactly what I did, and I switched to texstudio.  I guess one should set aside a fraction of his worktime to revisit the choice of tools.  My main frustration with TexWorks, I may be crazy, but I swear when I make a syntax error and get a fail-to-compile, then correct the error back to the previous known-good-state (as proven by a diff), TexWorks *still* fails to compile, until I exit it and remove the aux files.  A real productivity-killer, und es treibt mich in den Wahnsinn.  Thanks so much.

Comment: That problem is independent of your editor. Sometimes you do need to remove `aux` files (or similar) to proceed. However, I don't have to exit my editor to remove them and I wonder whether TS really requires this.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for that.  2 days on TecStudio & it's much better.  Recently on TexWorks it's been like chipping away at a block of granite, for equations and tables - type a line, make error, remove it, TexWorks refuses, try 45 minutes to regain last-known-good, remove aux files, start over.  I was at the point of backing up my .tex file every 15 minutes! I mayn't be able to prove it, but I'm convinced TexWorks is very, very unstable WRT LaTex errors.  In any case, TexStudio is considerably more sophisticated and robust, with *much* better error reporting and error recovery.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: That indeed sounds a pain. I hope TS works out better. I actually tried it the other day as Kile kept crashing. However, my preference is Kile as I like the built-in command line!